# Company Intranet, PHP/MySQL hosted locally on serve

Tags: php, mysql, intranet

I created an intranet for my company, but I’m having a problem. The files and MySQL tables are hosted on our local server, and is written in PHP. Basically it has a login system for employees and a bulletin board, calendar, etc.

Anyways, I created accounts for the employees, but nobody can login from their own computers, only my computer and the server computer. Is it because I only have PHP installed on these two computers? Do I need to install it on all computers?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You've got a fundamental misunderstanding of how webservers work - the PHP code runs on the server. That code generates HTML (or whatever) and sends it to the clients. The only thing the other computers need are browsers.

Comment: How do they connect to the server? What URL do they write?

Comment: Specify what you mean with ‘they can't login’. Isn't the page loading? Do they insert their username and password but nothing happens? Have you checked the path of the cookie? It's possibile that they're set to localhost or 127.0.0.1, that's different from the intranet IP.

Comment: The address is 192.168.1.5, our server uses IIS 6 if it is of any help. Basically when someone tries to logs in, they are just redirected to the same login page (which is supposed to happen if the username/password are incorrect).

Comment: Do you set some cookie to check the login status? Or do you just use sessions?

Comment: OK, I found out that other computers can login fine using Firefox, but they run into problems when using Internet Explorer. Is there a setting that disables scripts or something within PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your intranet ip address of server static . Type `ipconfig /all` in your command promt of server there will be ip address like 192.168.1.*  (not 192.168.1.1) copy that and then use it from other computers to access your local website.

Comment: Well it is already set to 192.168.1.5, does that sound correct?

Comment: yes it does sound correct what happen if you try to access this ip address from browser on the server and from some other PC??

Comment: OK well here's something: Other computers can access it no problem with Firefox, but IE blocks it. I'm completely lost!

Comment: Since its an intranet you can enforce your browser of choice easily which works . Lastly if you find my ans useful plz accept it then :)

Comment: OK, well is there a way to configure Internet Explorer to stop rejecting these scripts so I don't have to switch my entire company over?

Comment: Well maybe "rejecting scripts" wasn't the best phrasing on my part, but when a user attempts to login, the script either accepts them, creates a PHP session, and directs them to the main user page or rejects them and takes them back to the login screen. Every time a user with Internet Explorer tries to login, they are taken back to the login page whether or not the login info was correct. But with Firefox, I have no problems